# Prase error while creating wordpress site navigation bar

Tags: php, wordpress

The Codes I typed are:-

```
<nav class="site-nav[enter image description here][1]'>

<?php

       $args = arrray(
            'theme_location' => 'primary'
           );
 ?>

 <?php
       wp_nav_menu($args); 
  ?>

</nav>
```

Error Message:-

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\wamp64\www\wp-content\themes\MyFirstSite\header.php on line 23

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** [Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1011527). The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: You spelt array with 3 r's.

Comment: ok sir but i am beginner and i am curious to complete my webpage that's why i said this if i hurt anyone feeling then i am really sorry

Comment: i don't understand that if u don't mind please write the correct code

Comment: change arrray(
            'theme_location' => 'primary'
           ); to array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary'
           );

Comment: thanks you very much